# TypeError: 'getUserMedia' called on an object that does not implement interface MediaDevices

Tags: video, webcam, getusermedia

I'm trying to implement a webcam into a website using a video tag.
It works in Chrome, but FireFox and IE return errors in the console.
Anyone have any ideas why?
Thank you!

Code:

```
navigator.getMedia =    navigator.getUserMedia ||
                                navigator.webkitGetUserMedia ||
                                navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia ||
                                navigator.msGetUserMedia ||
                                OTPlugin.getUserMedia;
```

Firefox error:TypeError: 'getUserMedia' called on an object that does not implement interface MediaDevices.

IE error: Unable to get property 'getUserMedia' of undefined or null reference

Answer (score 15):

You forgot `navigator.mozGetUserMedia` for Firefox. IE doesn't have it (though MS Edge does).

Also, remove `navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia` from that list since it works differently.

***My advice:*** Skip the prefix mess and try [*adapter.js*](https://github.com/webrtc/adapter), the official WebRTC polyfill. Then use [*navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaDevices/getUserMedia) exclusively, as everything else has been deprecated.

Example (use [https fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/srn9db4h/) in Chrome):

```js
navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({ video: true, audio: true })
  .then(stream => video.srcObject = stream)
  .catch(e => console.log(e.name + ": "+ e.message));
```

```html
<video id="video" width="160" height="120" autoplay></video><br>
<script src="https://webrtc.github.io/adapter/adapter-latest.js"></script>
```

Comment: what do you mean by **since it works differently**? I figured the webrtc now returns a promise instead of accepting callbacks in its argument.. is there anything else im missing?

Comment: @choz Right, it doesn't work in practice to substitute one for the other like the OP was doing, since you have to call them differently.