# Webcam video stream not showing in html5 video tag

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to get access to a webcam and display video on an `HTML` page in a `video` tag. After I run the `HTML` page, I get a pop-up box asking for the permission to access webcam but after I grant permission, nothing happens. No video is shown in video tag. Below i the code. I am using Firefox 57.0

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>
        <title>webcam</title>
        <script type="text/javascript">
          var video = document.querySelector("#video");

          navigator.getUserMedia = navigator.getUserMedia || navigator.webkitGetUserMedia || navigator.mozGetUserMedia || navigator.msGetUserMedia || navigator.oGetUserMedia;

          if (navigator.getUserMedia) {
            alert('hello');
              navigator.getUserMedia( {
                  video : true
              },
              handleVideo, videoError);
          }

          function handleVideo(stream) {
              video.src = window.URL.createObjectURL(stream);
          }

          function videoError(e) {
              // do something
          }

        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <table border="1" width="900" align="center">
            <tr align="center">
                <td>
                    Web Camera
                    <div id="camera" style="height:300px; width:400px; border-style:solid;">
                        <video id="video" width="400" height="300"></video>
                    </div>
                </td>
                <td>
                    Photo Frame
                    <div id="frame" style="height:300px; width:400px; border-style:solid;">
                        <canvas id="canvas" width="400" height="300"></canvas>
                    </div>
                </td>
            </tr>

            <tr align="center">
                <td colspan="2">
                    <button id="snap" onclick="snap()">Snap Photo</button>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </body>
</html>
```

Kindly guide me what am I doing wrong. I've searched a lot but couldn't find anything.

Comment: Are you running from a `file://` URL? I can't remember for sure, but `getUserMedia` might need to run from an `http://` or `https://` origin.

Comment: running from http://localhost/test/web.html

Comment: @UsmanRiaz Already answered here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37673000/typeerror-getusermedia-called-on-an-object-that-does-not-implement-interface

Comment: See js fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/srn9db4h/

Answer (score 1):

Just set `autoplay` attr in `video` tag

```
<video autoplay id="video" > </video>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try below code :-
Just one change in your code. Execute your code after DOM is loaded fully. I have wrapped your code inside window.onload function.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>
        <title>webcam</title>
        <script type="text/javascript">
          window.onload = function(){
              document.querySelector("#video");
console.log(video);
          navigator.getUserMedia = navigator.getUserMedia || navigator.webkitGetUserMedia || navigator.mozGetUserMedia || navigator.msGetUserMedia || navigator.oGetUserMedia;

          if (navigator.getUserMedia) {
            alert('hello');
              navigator.getUserMedia( {
                  video : true
              },
              handleVideo, videoError);
          }

          function handleVideo(stream) {
              video.src = window.URL.createObjectURL(stream);
          }

          function videoError(e) {
              // do something
          }

          }; 
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <table border="1" width="900" align="center">
            <tr align="center">
                <td>
                    Web Camera
                    <div id="camera" style="height:300px; width:400px; border-style:solid;">
                        <video id="video" width="400" height="300"></video>
                    </div>
                </td>
                <td>
                    Photo Frame
                    <div id="frame" style="height:300px; width:400px; border-style:solid;">
                        <canvas id="canvas" width="400" height="300"></canvas>
                    </div>
                </td>
            </tr>

            <tr align="center">
                <td colspan="2">
                    <button id="snap" onclick="snap()">Snap Photo</button>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </body>
</html>
```

In above code you will not be able to see live preview.

Change handleVideo function to :-

```
function handleVideo(stream) {
          video.src = window.URL.createObjectURL(stream);
          video.play();
      }
```

After adding `video.play();` you will see live preview.

Comment: It's playing video when i run from a file but when i run it from weblogic server i doesn't play

Comment: @UsmanRiaz Did you checked the link mentioned in  above comments.